# can not create mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create procedure for query optimization but I am not being able to create, here is my SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE ` PROCEDURE `vaars_test_latest`.`geterpdata`(IN applicant_id VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT
    t2.start_date AS date_from_ad,
    t2.end_date AS date_to_ad,
    t1.job_id,
    t1.org_id,
    t1.seniority_date_bs AS seniority_date_bs,
    t1.seniority_Date AS seniority_date_ad,
    t5.name_en AS working_office,
    t5.id AS working_office_id,
    t7.name_en AS designation,
    t7.id AS designation_id,
    t8.name_en AS service_group,
    t8.id AS service_group_id,
    t9.name_en AS work_level,
    t9.id AS work_level_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.incharge = 1 THEN 'YES' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS is_office_incharge,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.incharge = 1 THEN t1.start_date 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS incharge_date_from_ad,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.incharge = 1 THEN t1.end_date 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS incharge_date_to_ad 
FROM
    erp_service_history t1 
LEFT JOIN
    temp1 t2 
        ON t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no 
        AND t1.job_id = t2.job_id 
        AND t1.org_id = t2.org_id 
INNER JOIN
    applicant_profile t4 
        ON t4.nt_staff_code = t1.emp_no 
LEFT JOIN
    erp_organization t3 
        ON t3.id = t1.org_id 
LEFT JOIN
    mst_working_office t5 
        ON t5.id = t3.working_office_id 
LEFT JOIN
    erp_jobs t6 
        ON t6.id = t1.job_id 
LEFT JOIN
    mst_designation t7 
        ON t7.id = t6.designation_id 
LEFT JOIN
    mst_work_service_group t8 
        ON t8.id = t6.service_group_id 
LEFT JOIN
    mst_work_level t9 
        ON t9.name_en = t1.grade 
WHERE
    t1.seniority_Date = t2.seniority_Date AND t4.id  = applicant_id
   ORDER BY
    t2.start_date DESC ;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

and it throws following exception:

> Query execution failed
>   Reason:
>   SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 61

On the line 61 is the ordery by line, please help.

Comment: Keep attention, you doesn't using any of your aliases ! And applicant_id isn't defined.

Comment: sorry for that, I have edited my question, applicant_id is the parameter to pass from procedure

Comment: Is the backtick before procedure a transcription error - if not it shouldn't be there and without sp compiles.

Comment: did not work removing that also

Comment: Compiles for me, what development tool are you using?

Comment: dbeaver , ubuntu